# special formatting of enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate

How can I tweak `enumerate` (or what else?) in order to achieve fixed-width run-in labels at the first enumeration level. That is, I want

```
This is some text before the list
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
  \end{enumerate}
```

to produce something like this (common in EU regulations, for example)

```
This is some text
before the list

(1)   This is an
item on the first
level and has a 
run-in label

(2)   This is an
item on the first
level and has a 
run-in label

a)  This is an item
    on the second 
    level and looks
    more familiar

b)  This is an item
    on the second 
    level and looks
    more familiar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this (margin narrowed for demonstration):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\textwidth=1.5in
\begin{document}
\noindent This is some text before the list
\begin{enumerate}[itemindent=17pt, leftmargin=0pt, label=(\arabic*)]
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
  \begin{enumerate}[itemindent=0pt, labelsep=10pt, leftmargin=20pt,label=\alph*)]
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe} % <---- remove in actual document.


\setlist[enumerate, 1]{label={(\arabic*)}, wide=0pt, widest=99, labelsep=15pt}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{label={\alph*)}, align=left,labelsep=*}
\begin{document}

This is some text before the list. This is some text before the list. This is some text before the list. This is some text before the list. 
\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar 
  \item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do these customized indentations by many options provided by the enumitem package, this is an MWE based on your question:

```
% pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
This is some text before the list
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin = 0.25\textwidth, rightmargin = 0.25\textwidth]
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
\item This is an item on the first level and has a run-in label
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\arabic*]
\item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
\item This is an item on the second level and looks more familiar
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The 1st level should have different alignment on the left.

Comment: @Sigur OP may use various options in the packages. There is some alignment options as well.